# My reducers keep returning undefined despite the fact that data is being accessed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am working on a React Native application which has a facebook login feature that is working, the action creator and reducer is working just fine for that, but the action creators and reducers for the job search API I am using is not working.

These are the action creators:

```
import axios from "axios";
// import { Location } from "expo";
import qs from "qs";

import { FETCH_JOBS, LIKE_JOB } from "./types";
import locationify from "../tools/locationify";

const JOB_ROOT_URL = "https://authenticjobs.com/api/?";

const JOB_QUERY_PARAMS = {
  api_key: "<api_key>",
  method: "aj.jobs.search",
  perpage: "10",
  format: "json",
  keywords: "javascript"
};

const buildJobsUrl = () => {
  const query = qs.stringify({ ...JOB_QUERY_PARAMS });
  return `${JOB_ROOT_URL}${query}`;
};

export const fetchJobs = (
  region,
  distance = 10,
  callback
) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = buildJobsUrl();
    let job_list = await axios.get(url);
    job_list = locationify(
      region,
      console.log(job_list.data.listings.listing),
      job_list.data.listings.listing,
      distance,
      (obj, coords) => {
        obj.company.location = { ...obj.company.location, coords };
        return obj;
      }
    );
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: job_list });
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("fetchJobs Action Error:", e.message);
  }
};

export const likeJob = job => {
  return {
    payload: job,
    type: LIKE_JOB
  };
};
```

This is the `jobs_reducer.js`:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listings: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is the `likes_reducer.js`:

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { LIKE_JOB } from "../actions/types";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIKE_JOB:
      return _.uniqBy([action.payload, ...state], "id");
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I spent all evening yesterday debugging this and all I know is that I am console logging data to my terminal, I can see the details of the jobs API data just populate my terminal, but the error message is that the reducers are returning undefined.

How can I return data and return undefined simultaneously?

I am using an asynchronous action creator. Do I need `redux-thunk` on a React Native application? Am I using a version of React Native that has a bug right now? I know how Redux is supposed to work and so I am stumped here.

In `reducers/index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import auth from "./auth_reducer";
import jobs from "./jobs_reducer";
import likedJobs from "./likes_reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  jobs,
  likedJobs
});
```

Where I start to get that error or what the error is referencing is the `this.props.data.map()` as in the `components/Swipe.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  Dimensions,
  LayoutAnimation,
  UIManager
} from "react-native";

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 0.25 * SCREEN_WIDTH;
const SWIPE_OUT_DURATION = 250;

class Swipe extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onSwipeRight: () => {},
    onSwipeLeft: () => {},
    keyProp: "id"
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const position = new Animated.ValueXY();
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy });
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dx > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
          this.forceSwipe("right");
        } else if (gestureState.dx < -SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
          this.forceSwipe("left");
        } else {
          this.resetPosition();
        }
      }
    });

    this.state = { panResponder, position, index: 0 };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.setState({ index: 0 });
    }
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
  }

  forceSwipe(direction) {
    const x = direction === "right" ? SCREEN_WIDTH : -SCREEN_WIDTH;
    Animated.timing(this.state.position, {
      toValue: { x, y: 0 },
      duration: SWIPE_OUT_DURATION
    }).start(() => this.onSwipeComplete(direction));
  }

  onSwipeComplete(direction) {
    const { onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight, data } = this.props;
    const item = data[this.state.index];
    direction === "right" ? onSwipeRight(item) : onSwipeLeft(item);
    this.state.position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1 });
  }

  resetPosition() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.position, {
      toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }).start();
  }

  getCardStyle() {
    const { position } = this.state;
    const rotate = position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.5, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.5],
      outputRange: ["-120deg", "0deg", "120deg"]
    });
    return {
      ...position.getLayout(),
      transform: [{ rotate }]
    };
  }

  renderCards() {
    if (this.state.index >= this.props.data.length) {
      return this.props.renderNoMoreCards();
    }

    return this.props.data
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i < this.state.index) {
          return null;
        }

        if (i === this.state.index) {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={item[this.props.id]}
              style={[this.getCardStyle(), styles.cardStyle]}
              {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}
            >
              {this.props.renderCard(item)}
            </Animated.View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={item[this.props.id]}
            style={[styles.cardStyle, { top: 10 * (i - this.state.index) }]}
          >
            {this.props.renderCard(item)}
          </Animated.View>
        );
      })
      .reverse();
  }

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderCards()}</View>;
  }
}

const styles = {
  cardStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH
  }
};

export default Swipe;
```

Above I am getting that `this.props.data.map()` is either undefined or is not a function.

I get the same issue in `ReviewScreen.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ReviewScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Review Jobs",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        title="Settings"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("settings");
        }}
      />
    )
  });

  renderLikedJobs() {
    return this.props.likedJobs.map(job => {
      return (
        <Card>
          <View style={{ height: 200 }}>
            <View style={styles.detailWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.italics}>{job.company}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.italics}>{job.post_date}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <ScrollView>{this.renderLikedJobs()}</ScrollView>;
  }
}

const styles = {
  detailWrapper: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { jobs: state.jobs };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReviewScreen);
```

Same thing above with `this.props.likedJobs.map()`

Comment: Can't see how you are using those reducers in the code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX, I added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring my jobs reducer like so:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      const { listings } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, listing: listings.listing };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your API, in your action creator, Hardcore the API data and return it. If your reducer keeps returning undefined the error is in your code.

For async calls you need to use redux-thunk or redux-saga, i would recommend you redux-saga because it avoids callback hell.

Comment: I am no longer getting an error that says the problem is with the reducer, now I just get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.data.length')`, which I was already getting before, but since I am getting the same error with hardcoded data, I would conclude the problem is in my code, the question is where? But then if I remove the whole `Swipe.js` component completely. I start to get the reducer being the problem error again, so, it puts me no further in resolving this.

Comment: Your swipe.js is meant to render a single card or multiple cards?? Maybe you forgot to connect the data to your component thats why this.props.data is undefined.One last thing: calling it data isn't a good variable name,rename it if possible.

Comment: the issue is definitely in my `jobs_reducer.js` code.

Comment: How are you passing the "data" props to your swipe.js??